# More than one alarms in alarmManager

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alarmmanager

This is an sms timer app so i need to set multiple alarms using alarm manager so that i can send messages to many people.
my code is :

```
Phone = phone.getText().toString();
        Message = message.getText().toString();
        phone.setText("");
        message.setText("");
        //Validating if any field empty
        if (Phone.length() >= 10 && Message.length() > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Your sms will be sent soon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Getting Calender Reference
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (currentApiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time_picker.getMinute());
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time_picker.getHour());
            } else {
                //Setting the date and time from the time picker
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time_picker.getCurrentMinute());
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time_picker.getCurrentHour());
            }

            int a = (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND) * 1000);

            myIntent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
            //Pending Intent for sending the intent afterwards
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) (this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis() - a, pendingIntent);
```

All the code in in an onclick function, so when the user fills the data and clicks send it should set an alarm.
I only need at most 5 alarms.
I tries creating `AlarmManager[]` and `ArrayList<PendingIntent>` but it didnt work, only the latest alarm is getting set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PendingIntents are usually difrenciated by their requestCode (works like an ID), that may be what's causing your problem, you can set the requestCode like this:

Add this outside of onCreate:

```
static int i;
```

and replace this:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
```

with this:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), i++ /*this number is the PendingIntent's requestCode*/, myIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Do I have to create an array of smsManager and araaylist of pending intent too

Comment: I assume the user user sends a new message when he clicks on the button, and all that code is inside that onClick(), so everytime the user clicks it, it creates a new PendingIntent, but your code it will create a new one with the same requestCode and that doesnt really create a new one, it replaces the one with the same requestCode, see edited answer

Comment: Ya right so what else can I do to make it a new pending intent every time the user click the button